# Why does the shape of a Pandas DataFrame change after reading/loading a saved file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want my code to accomplish the following:

- Check if there is any file in the folder named 'ledger'. THIS WORKS.
- If no, make a file. THIS WORKS.
- If yes, read the file, update contents in the file, and save the file maintaining the shape of the file. THIS DOESN'T WORK.

I tried the code below:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
from os import listdir


# DEFINE PATH, STATE SUFFIX OF FILE, AND GET NUMBER OF FILES ENDING WITH SUFFIX
path = r'ledger'
suff = r'.csv'
file = listdir(path)
file = [item for item in file if item.endswith(suff)]


# CHECK IF LEDGER IS AVAILABLE, AND IF NOT, CREATE ONE
if len(file) == 0:
    save = np.zeros([1, 7])
    save = pd.DataFrame(save, columns = ['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Ticker', 'Type', 'Quantity', 'Value'])
    print(save.shape)
    print(save)
    save.to_csv(os.path.join(path, r'ledger.csv'))
else:
    load = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, r'ledger.csv'))
    load = pd.DataFrame(load)
    print(load.shape)
    print(load)
```

If the file doesn't exist, the print functions produce the following:

```
(1, 7)
   Year  Month  Day  Ticker  Type  Quantity  Value
0   0.0    0.0  0.0     0.0   0.0       0.0    0.0
```

However, if the file exists, the file is read and the print functions product the following:

```
(1, 8)
   Unnamed: 0  Year  Month  Day  Ticker  Type  Quantity  Value
0           0   0.0    0.0  0.0     0.0   0.0       0.0    0.0
```

I am not sure what I can do to keep the size of the DataFrame intact. It seems like the index of the original file is getting added when being loaded as a DataFrame. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that when you are writing to the file, you write the indices too.

```
save.to_csv(os.path.join(path, r'ledger.csv'), index = False)
```

this will prevent writing the index to file. When you read this file it should have seven columns